# I am getting a block twice in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I am trying to create a static block on my homepage. So I added Static Block to the CMS Page Layout Update XML FIeld

Here is my code:

```
<reference name="left_first"> 
    <block type="cms/block" name="Offers"  before="-">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>offer-link</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Here I was expecting one block in the left side of my Home page and i am getting that but in addition to this i am getting it twice.

[image]

Comment: Could you post how you declare the `left_first` reference ?

Comment: I simply added the above code in home page  Layout Update XML FIeld. Actually i copied this from somewhere. I am using rwd theme.. i dont know wheather it is correct or wrong. i am new to this.. :(

Comment: What if you get rid of the `before="-"` ?

Comment: Maybe `left_first` is added twice somewhere in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. i have removed  before="-". now its working fine as expected.. :)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism why before = "-" and output="toHtml" cause it to show twice? can you please share the reason, so it will help other in future?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I have used the same block name for multiple blocks. When I made sure they are all unique, then It was rendered just once.